# Carregando 2 form em uma mesma página e salvando eles

Tags: django, django-2.0

Tenho um sistema, e preciso alterar, quero tirar a opção pets, e por ela em um tabela separa, por que terá mais de um tipo de usuario que utilizaria ela.
Mas não estou conseguindo fazer ela aparecer junto com o outro form na mesma página e depois preciso que salve ambos formulários ao mesmo tempo.
lembrando que cada vez que cadastro o formulário, um usuario é criado no sistema pelo UserCreationForm
precisaria de uma ajuda para poder mostrar e salvar ambos formulario de uma única vez

models.py

```
class Pets(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    pets = models.CharField(max_length=255, choices=PET_CHOICES)

class Usuario(models.Model):

    nome = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=False)
    sobrenome = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=False)
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    email = models.EmailField(blank=False)
```

forms.py

```
   class PetsForm(forms.ModelForm):
   pets = forms.MultipleChoiceField(
          widget=forms.CheckboxSelectMultiple, choices=PET_CHOICES, )
   class Meta:
          model = Pets
          fields = '__all__' 
   class UsuarioForm(UserCreationForm):

   nome = forms.CharField()
   sobrenome = forms.CharField(
          widget=forms.TextInput(
                                      attrs={
                                             'placeholder': 'Sobrenome'}))
   email = forms.EmailField(
          widget=forms.TextInput(
                                      attrs={
                                             'placeholder': 'Email Válido', 'id': 'email'}))
```

views.py

```
def cadastro(request):
    usuario = Usuario.objects.all() 
    form = UsuarioForm()
    pets = Pets.objects.all()
    form2 = PetsForm()
    data = {'usuario': usuario, 'form': form}
    data2 = {'pets': pets, 'form2': form2}
    return render(request, 'cadastro.html', data, data2)


def cadastro_novo(request): 
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = UsuarioForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
        form2 = PetsForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid() and form2.is_valid():
            user = form.save(commit=False)
            user.is_active = False
            user.is_staff = True
            user = form.save()
            user.refresh_from_db()  # load the profile instance created by the signal
            user.usuario.nome = form.cleaned_data.get('nome')
            user.usuario.sobrenome = form.cleaned_data.get('sobrenome')
            user.usuario.email = form.cleaned_data.get('email')
            user.usuario.telefone = form.cleaned_data.get('telefone')
            user.usuario.cidade = form.cleaned_data.get('cidade')
            user.usuario.endereco = form.cleaned_data.get('endereco')
            user.usuario.cpf = form.cleaned_data.get('cpf')
            user.usuario.numero = form.cleaned_data.get('numero')
            user.usuario.bairro = form.cleaned_data.get('bairro')
            user.usuario.cep = form.cleaned_data.get('cep')
            user.usuario.password1 = form.cleaned_data.get('password1')
            user.usuario.data_nascimento = form.cleaned_data.get('data_nascimento')
            user.usuario.gallery_usuario = form.cleaned_data.get('gallery_usuario')
            user.usuario.pet = form.cleaned_data.get('pets')
            user.usuario.foto = form.cleaned_data.get('foto')
            user.usuario.sexo = form.cleaned_data.get('sexo')
            user.usuario.estado = form.cleaned_data.get('estado')
            user.usuario.about = form.cleaned_data.get('about')
            user.pets.pet = form.cleaned_data.get('pet')
            username = form.cleaned_data.get('username')
            user.username = username.lower()
            user.save()
            current_site = get_current_site(request)
            subject = 'Ative seu registro no PetAqui'
            message = render_to_string('account_activation_email.html', {
                'user': user,
                'domain': current_site.domain,
                'uid': urlsafe_base64_encode(force_bytes(user.pk)).decode(),
                'token': account_activation_token.make_token(user),
            })
            user.email_user(subject, message)
            return redirect('account_activation_sent')
    else:
        form = UsuarioForm()
    return render(request, 'cadastro.html', {'form': form})


def account_activation_sent(request):
    return render(request, 'account_activation_sent.html')
```

cadastro.html estou chamando assim

```
{{ form.nome | as_crispy_field }}
{{ form.sobrenome | as_crispy_field }}
{{ form.user | as_crispy_field }}
{{ form.email | as_crispy_field }}
{{ form2.pets | as_crispy_field }}
```

Answer (score -1):

Bom dia,

Cara, eu precisei fazer algo semelhante no meu sistema, tenho várias tabelas diferentes no banco, logo, vários forms diferentes renderizados na mesma pagina. Não sei se a forma que fiz é a mais "correta" ou melhor, mas, criei uma UpdateView e fiz o seguinte:

```
def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
    kwargs['franqueado'] = CadastroDeFranqueado.objects.get(pk=self.kwargs['pk'])
    kwargs['form_franqueado'] = CadastroDeFranqueadoCompletoForm(self.request.POST or None, instance=kwargs['franqueado'])
    kwargs['comentarios'] = ComentariosCrm.objects.filter(franquia__pk=self.kwargs['pk'])
    kwargs['form_comentario'] = ComentariosCrmForm(self.request.POST or None)
    return super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
```

No código acima fiz o load dos forms e dos dados pré-existentes, depois, usei o metodo "form_valid" com um if para cada form onde verifico um por um se há dados a serem salvos, veja:

```
def form_valid(self, form, **kwargs):
    try:
        user = User.objects.get(username=self.franqueado().usuario)
    except:
        user = User.objects.get(email=self.franqueado().emailPrincipal)
    form = form.save()
    if self.franqueado().emailPrincipal != user.email:
        user.email = self.franqueado().emailPrincipal
        user.save()

    if self.franqueado().usuario != user.username:
        user.username = self.franqueado().usuario
        user.save()

    if self.franqueado().status != 'Operando' and self.franqueado().status != 'Em implantação':
        user.is_active = False
        user.save()
    else:
        user.is_active = True
        user.save()

    formcomentario = ComentariosCrmForm(self.request.POST or None)
    if formcomentario.is_valid():
        if len(
            formcomentario.cleaned_data.get('autor')
        ) > 3 and len(
            formcomentario.cleaned_data.get('comentario')
        ) > 5 and formcomentario.cleaned_data.get(
            'franquia'
        ):
            formcomentario.save()

    formdocumentos = DocumentosCrmForm(self.request.POST or None, self.request.FILES or None)
    if formdocumentos.is_valid():
        docs = self.request.FILES.getlist('documento')
        for doc in docs:
            documento = DocumentosCrm(franquia=self.franqueado(), documento=doc)
            documento.save()
    return super().form_valid(form)
```

Espero que o código acima possa te auxiliar na resolução do problema.

Comment: Amigo, final de semana vou tentar e qualquer coisa te mando msg, muito obrigadi

Comment: Show, espero que de certo o/